# Pyvmomi - How to get vm's IP without VMTools installed?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, vsphere

In general, my goal is to get the IP of a VM that **doesn't have VMTools installed**, by it's name.

The docs of FindByIp says

> The IP address for a virtual machine is the one returned from VMware tools, ipAddress .

(from https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/SearchIndex.rst)

So I'm wondering if it's this information is even accessible?
And if so - how can I get to it by the VM's name?

Answer (score 1):

To get an instance through the name of a VM, use ContainerView to find the same name in every VM list.
Then, after obtaining an instance of the VM,

```
vm.guest.ipAddress
```

See Using ContainerView.

Comment: This seems to only work when vmware tools is installed